# Updating user data in default Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just started using Laravel and I can't get my head around this problem... I hope more experienced people here can spot the error I'm making.

I configured a fresh laravel application and performed

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Following the instructions from
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart.

These are all routes in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@show');
Route::get('/user', ['as'=>"user", 'uses'=>'UserController@show']);
Route::post('/user/update', ['as' => 'user.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

This is my `UserController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function show() {

    return view('user')->withUser(Auth::user());
  }
  public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->name=$request->input('name');
        $user->email=$request->input('email');

        $user->save();
        return Redirect::route('user');
    }
}
```

And this is the form in my `user.blade.php`:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<tr><th colspan=2>My data</th></tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>E-mail address</td>
      <td>{!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2>{!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}</td></tr>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Nothing seems to happen when I click the submit button in the form... Data is not changed in the database.

**Updates**:

- The controller doesn't get triggered. I added `dd()` to the `update()` function and this doesn't yield anything.
- I tried `composer du`, clearing the browser cache and tried another browser. I refreshed the migration using `php artisan migrate:fresh` and registered again. Same problem still. debug is set to true, I get other errors if I change things. I added the project to a github repo: [github.com/EsthervdS/LaravelTest](https://github.com/EsthervdS/LaravelTest)
- I reinstalled a whole new project and the problem occurs again.

Comment: is the page reloading? see if the $error variable is populated once you post In blade add <?php {{ $error->all(); }} ?> and see if it shows any error after post.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I get this error: Undefined variable: error (View: /<...>/resources/views/user.blade.php)

Comment: I changed it to $errors->all() and the page does not show any error after posting the form.

Comment: can you post the contents of your log file, it should be in the storage/logs folder. Also see if your call is even reaching your controller by adding a dd() at the beginning of your controller.

Comment: I added dd() to the controller but nothing changes..? That would imply the flow never reaches the controller?

Comment: I also tried `{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

Comment: try to remove brackets in route name

Comment: Tried removing the brackets, but it didn't work :(
Also tried rewriting the form: `<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.update') }}">` but no solution either.

Comment: @pseudoanime In the log file I find no logs from the last 2 hours...

Comment: @esther exactly, if you've added dd() to the top and it hasn't been triggered, then the controller function hasn't triggered. We need to look at the view/route now.

Comment: @pseudoanime I updated my question to include all routes and the updated form in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after looking at your **user.blade.php** found that you are using form inside table and that's what preventing form submission. also i found more mistakes too. so i improved it.

Mistakes found:

- form submit inside table
- duplicate route names
- no auth middleware to user routes
- no data validation
- using wrong use statements

**user.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Profile</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        @if($errors)
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    {{ $error }}
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif

                        {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                            </div>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

i'm not big fan of laravel collective

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return view('user', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Get current user
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

        // Validate the data submitted by user
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:225|'. Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
        ]);

        // if fails redirects back with errors
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        // Fill user model
        $user->fill([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email
        ]);

        // Save user to database
        $user->save();

        // Redirect to route
        return redirect()->route('user');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

// Auth routes
Auth::routes();

// User account routes
Route::get('user', 'UserController@show')->name('user');
Route::post('user/update', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');

// other routes
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**extra tip**
i'll recommend to use [laravel authorization policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies).
and if you also want to make welcome route only available to authenticate users then simply add auth middleware to welcome route - [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: Thanks @Priyash for taking the time and explaining the mistakes I made!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

to

```
$userDetails = Auth::user();  // To get the logged-in user details
$user = User::find($userDetails ->id);  // Find the user using model and hold its reference
$user->name=$request->input('name');
$user->email=$request->input('email');

$user->save();  // Update the data
```

`Auth::user();` contains the logged-in user data in it i.e. the data we mostly put in the session, but to update the user data you have to use the model instance or query builder.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to respond to clicking the submit button. But it turns out the controller isn't even reached...

Comment: I have to update logged in user's name and phone number in session after updating profile information by form. How to update Auth session with latest user information? Thanks.